# Calculate scaling prices PHP dont show up

Tags: php, calculation

I'm trying to change the scaling prize on the reservation system on PHP. The part of the system was

```
<?php echo DateTime::secondsToInterval( 3600 * 2 ) ?>" data-text-1="<?php echo DateTime::secondsToInterval( 3600 * 2 ) ?> (<?php echo Price::format( 40 * 2 ) ?>)"></option>
```

The problem becomes when I try to change the price value `<?php echo Price::format( 40 * 2 **- 190**) ?>`
The system still shows the same result with no change.
I tried clear cache but still no result.
Do you know, how i can't fix it? Can you help, please?
Thank you
Wish you a fantastic day :)
Jana

Comment: That's some pretty crazy math in your revised `Price::format()` call - and will generate an error. Without any definition of what parameters that function takes, I'd guess that you are missing some quotes.

Comment: Show code of Price::format().